# RecurrenceTable

Tags: syntax, list-manipulation, recursion

I got an error saying

```
RecurrenceTable::deqn: "Equation or list of equations expected instead of s[n]-3/100\ E^(-0.05\n)\ i[n]\ s[n] in the first argument {s[n]-3/100\ E^(-0.05\n)\ i[n]\ s[n],3/100\ E^(-0.05\n)\ i[n]\ s[n],99,1}. "
```

When I entered the following code:

```
RecurrenceTable[{s[n + 1] = s[n] - (3*s[n]*i[n])/(E^(0.05*n)*100), 
i[n + 1] = (3*s[n]*i[n])/(E^(0.05*n)*100), s[0] = 99, i[0] = 1}, {s,i}, {n, 1, 30}]
```

I wonder what's going wrong this piece of code? I have tried to match the exact format I found in Wolfram documentation center, yet my code won't work.

Comment: = not = to == ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rewriting rasher's terse comment above.
You should use the `==` (Equal) operator and not `=` (Set) ,because the last one is used only for assigning values to symbols.
Like this:

```
RecurrenceTable[
 {s[n + 1] == s[n] - (3*s[n]*i[n])/(E^(0.05*n)*100), 
  i[n + 1] == (3*s[n]*i[n])/(E^(0.05*n)*100), 
  s[0] == 99, 
  i[0] == 1}, {s, i}, {n, 1, 30}]

    (* {{96.03, 2.97}, {87.891, 8.13898}, {68.4729, 19.4181}, {34.1407, 
  34.3323}, {5.351, 28.7897}, {1.75169, 3.59931}, {1.61157, 
  0.140123}, {1.60679, 0.00477392}, {1.60664, 0.000154255}, {1.60663, 
  4.74073*10^-6}, {1.60663, 1.38591*10^-7}, {1.60663, 
  3.85399*10^-9}, {1.60663, 1.01946*10^-10}, {1.60663, 
  2.56518*10^-12}, {1.60663, 6.13974*10^-14}, {1.60663, 
  1.39787*10^-15}, {1.60663, 3.02739*10^-17}, {1.60663, 
  6.23672*10^-19}, {1.60663, 1.22216*10^-20}, {1.60663, 
  2.27817*10^-22}, {1.60663, 4.03952*10^-24}, {1.60663, 
  6.81331*10^-26}, {1.60663, 1.09313*10^-27}, {1.60663, 
  1.66829*10^-29}, {1.60663, 2.4219*10^-31}, {1.60663, 
  3.34445*10^-33}, {1.60663, 4.39319*10^-35}, {1.60663, 
  5.48934*10^-37}, {1.60663, 6.52447*10^-39}, {1.60663, 
  7.3766*10^-41}} *)
```

Comment: But this is what I got: RecurrenceTable[{True, True, True, True}, {s, i}, {n, 1, 30}] Error:RecurrenceTable::deqn: "Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {True,True,True,True}. "

Comment: @BohanLu Try it again after restarting Mathematica. The problem is likely that you already assigned values to your symbols by using `Set`, so the whole thing is misbehaving.